# Want to Display a LInk for Screen Only TCPDF

Tags: hyperlink, screen, tcpdf

I am working on pdf Using TCPDF library, i want to display a link on PDF generated, but for screen only and not to be printed when the document is printed.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like everything points to

```
$pdf->setVisibility('screen');
```

before your line

https://hotexamples.com/examples/-/TCPDF/startLayer/php-tcpdf-startlayer-method-examples.html

after,

```
$pdf->setVisibility('all');
```